# Unexpected value 'SohoComponentsModule' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am writing an angular 2 application and am using our UI team's library. The development of the application is going great, I can use all of their components easily by using an import statement like so. This is my app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { SohoComponentsModule } from '@infor/sohoxi-angular'; // This is the one in question.

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { licenseGeneratorComponent } from './licenseGenerator.component';
import { emergencyLicenseComponent } from './tabs/emergency/emergencyLicense.component';
import { partnerLicenseComponent } from './tabs/partner/partnerLicense.component';
import { standardLicenseComponent } from './tabs/standard/standardLicense.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    licenseGeneratorComponent,
    emergencyLicenseComponent,
    partnerLicenseComponent,
    standardLicenseComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    SohoComponentsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and here is one of my templates used within this app, the soho stuff is from this library:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns">
  <h1>License Generator</h1>
    <div soho-tabs>
      <ul soho-tab-list>
        <li soho-tab><a soho-tab-title tabId='tabs-normal-emergency'>Emergency Licenses</a></li>
        <li soho-tab><a soho-tab-title tabId='tabs-normal-partner'>Partner Licenses</a></li>
        <li soho-tab><a soho-tab-title tabId='tabs-normal-standard'>Standard Licenses</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div soho-tab-panel tabId='tabs-normal-emergency'>
        <emergency-license></emergency-license>
      </div>
      <div soho-tab-panel tabId='tabs-normal-partner'>
        <partner-license></partner-license>
      </div>
      <div soho-tab-panel tabId='tabs-normal-standard'>
        <standard-license></standard-license>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The application has been working just fine, no issues. But when there is an issue with my unit tests now. I had them working before with the first few unit tests but left it alone for a week or so and added more content and now the tests don't run properly.

When I run my tests I get the error

```
Unexpected value 'SohoComponentsModule' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'
```

My app.component.spec looks like this:

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { licenseGeneratorComponent } from './licenseGenerator.component';
import { emergencyLicenseComponent } from './tabs/emergency/emergencyLicense.component';
import { partnerLicenseComponent } from './tabs/partner/partnerLicense.component';
import { standardLicenseComponent } from './tabs/standard/standardLicense.component';

import { SohoComponentsModule } from '@infor/sohoxi-angular';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        licenseGeneratorComponent,
        emergencyLicenseComponent,
        partnerLicenseComponent,
        standardLicenseComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        SohoComponentsModule
      ],
    });
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it(`should have as title 'app works!'`, async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('app works!');
  }));
});
```

I am going in circles now though because if I remove the import statement in the test it throws these errors:

```
Can't bind to 'closeOnSelect' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. ("label required">Versions</label>
```

Please Help!

Keep in mind the application works just fine still, just the unit tests that are giving me issues. I've spent all day looking around for fixes but can't figure this out.

Please let me know if I need to post more of my files.
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason it was the angular library that was causing this issue.
I updated the version and the issue was fixed.